# Improving performance using rand()

Tags: julia, montecarlo

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation of the Ising model. Overall the code is pretty efficient. The function below is called around 10 million times:

```
function stepFlip(sim::Ising)
    i = rand(1:sim.n)
    j = rand(1:sim.n)

    dE = dEnergy(i, j, sim)

    if dE < 0 || rand() < exp(-dE/sim.T)
        sim.spins[i,j] *= -1
    end
end
```

Is there a way for me to optimize the random number generation, which is what takes most of the execution time? I know it could be faster for to pre-generate all of them and just read them as I call stepFlip, but at that point is it worth it to allocate all that memory if my goal is performance?

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html) can help you. Also, there are many PRNGs around, sometimes with huge performance differences -- and Mersenne Twister, which is the default in Julia, can be quite slow, IIRC. But you should test it -- several implementations can be found [here](https://github.com/sunoru/RandomNumbers.jl).

Comment: Are you sure that `rand`s take most of the time? Have you profiled the simulation? At around 10M, I would guess `rand`s take less than a second in total.

Comment: On my (old laptop) computer, running `rand(1:100)` twice times 10 million, takes 0.2 seconds. Is that really a bottleneck? Pre-generating them is not likely to be faster, but it _will_ use more memory.

Comment: There are fast random number generators for julia implemented in https://github.com/sunoru/RandomNumbers.jl . If rand is really your bottleneck this is your only way of speeding up the generation. The Xoroshiro family has some good fast ones, but it all depends on your randomness/speed tradeoff

Comment: There is also a faster implementation of `rand(a:b)` in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/29240

Comment: Great, thanks so much everyone for the input.